# Cannot create KeySpace using Cassandra-CLI

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface

I have installed and started up `Cassandra server(1.0.8)`. I can connect to the server using the `CLI` application. But as soon as I try to create a keyspace `"twissandra"` following the step from [CassandraCLI](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli)

I end up getting the following error
[image]

I can see the `cassandra.yaml` file in `"config" directory` of the installation.

### EDIT - THE ANSWER

OK So after a few days of short chitty chats with [libjack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31713/libjack). The error was tracked down.

```
REM set CLASSPATH="%CASSANDRA_HOME%\conf"
```

The line above is a remark (comment if you may) I had to go through the whole `BAT file` line by line before finally removing the `REM` clause.

Comment: check the log for the stacktrace which might explain why the cassandra.yaml cannot be found. Plus update the appender in log4j-server.properties to specify a correct path: log4j.appender.R.File=H:/logs/cassandra.log

Comment: Well thanks you for the answer. It is quite odd that I need to specify so many things for cassandra to run! Let me give it a try...

Comment: @libjack- I tried your solution. I see the log files at the correct location. But there is still no luck in creating the keyspace...

Comment: @libjack - I finally made it...but the solution is absolutely unacceptable. I had to copy the file cassandra.yaml from conf folder to bin folder. I hope some other options must be out there to get this properly fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cassandra.yaml is expected to be found in the classpath. By default, the cassandra.bat (my  version from 1.07 zip) adds the $CASSANDRA_HOME\conf directory to the classpath (as well as other necessary Jars)

If CASSANDRA_HOME is not set, it uses the directory above the script location.

To test, perhaps modify the cassandra.bat to echo out all the commands and see where things get messed up.

Comment: I have been going through all the bat file. The CASSANDRA_HOME\conf is added to the class path. With the following lines from the bat file. 
REM Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup
set CLASSPATH="%CASSANDRA_HOME%\conf"

Therefore it seems that something else is wrong. I have added all the JAVA_HOME,JRE_HOME,CASSANDRA_HOME paths to environment variables. But still unless I have the yaml file in bin directory...I cant create key spaces.  The only variable I was not sure about was "%CASSANDRA_MAIN%" and may be you can give me a hint about it.

Comment: Can you verify in the log output? During startup, I see INFO messages which show the CLASSPATH and then a URL for cassandra.yaml resource.

Comment: I have uploaded the log file  here If you can go through the first 10 lines that were written when I removed cassandra.yaml from bin to conf folder. Rest of the log is a correct run. http://www.hyperfileshare.com/d/f63ce908

Comment: OK, I would expect the CLASSPATH to contain the conf folder first, but in your log, I just see a leading ";"

Comment: I was suspicious myself about that leading ";" but not sure why.

Comment: Yes, so I would say that cassandra.bat is not correctly getting CASSANDRA_HOME and/or failing to put CASSANDRA_HOME\conf in that first location of the CLASSPATH.

Comment: let me see if I can force it somehow to get the correct path.

Comment: Well holy cows! Here is the line that was causing the trouble...My God why was it REM'd in the first place??  REM set CLASSPATH="%CASSANDRA_HOME%\conf"

Comment: Marking as an answer as you have helped me all the way... Thank you :) Just vote me up a bit :)

Comment: I have edited my question and placing the solution with your reference.

Comment: @jbellis Well I had downloaded the latest version. Never knew that this was fixed.

Comment: Ah, looks like only an issue in 1.0.8, fixed in 1.0.9 .. and I'm still at 1.0.7, so wasn't seeing it.

Comment: @libjack - So all is well that ends well :)